# Java Servlet, Send a redirect with html tags

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I'm looking for a way to send a redirection with my servlet from my first page to a second page adding into the second page a script tag made inside this servlet.

For example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Received a get request");
    response.getWriter().append("<script>alert(\"I'm here!\")</script>");
    response.sendRedirect("testRedirect.html");
}
```

This code doesn't work. How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: What errors do you face?In browser or server console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for your answers I solved with this code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("received a get message");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<script>alert(\"I'm here\");</script>");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("testRedirect.html").include(request, response);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: What I am curious to know is why did this work with requestDispatcher and not with the redirect?

Answer (score 1):

`response.sendRedirect` writes the redirect header to the output stream. Headers must be sent before any output, this is why your code doesn't work.

Try swapping the two statements, redirecting first and then appending:

```
response.sendRedirect("testRedirect.html");
response.getWriter().append("<script>alert(\"I'm here!\")</script>");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I tried and nothing to do. It doesn't work also this way. Any other idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send the content of the second page inside the redirection response. There are actually two requests.

The first request is handled by your servlet by sending the redirect. There should nothing else in this response.

The browser receives the redirect and does a second request to "testRedirect.html". If you want to include the script tag in the second response the right place to do it is the servlet or JSP which handles this second request.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the user to the desired page by using javascript instead.

```
out.println("<script> alert(\"I'm here\"); window.location.replace(\"testRedirect.html\"); </script>");
```